# Read and Write JSON Strings from Kafka Topic using Kafka Streams in Java

Tags: java, json, performance, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams (1.1.0) as maven dependency and I want to consume messages which are in JSON format directly using JSONSerde rather than using mapValues functionality. Is there any performance advantage of using JSONSerde compared to manually converting Strings to JSON using mapValues function. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Using a direct byte-to-Json conversion should be faster. Parsing a String should be more expensive. But I don't have any benchmarks to back this up -- it's just what I expect. Best bet: try it out and run a benchmark :)

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax . Can you provide me small example regarding how to use JSONSerde. Or a link that describe this with Kafka 1.1.0 version.

Comment: Google "Kafka Stream Json Serde" -> https://github.com/amient/hello-kafka-streams/blob/master/src/main/java/io/amient/examples/wikipedia/WikipediaStreamDemo.java

Comment: Thanks. @MatthiasJ.Sax I think this is not compatible with 1.1.0 version as Stream function is only accepting topic name. It gives me error when I try as builder.stream(jsonSerde, jsonSerde , streamConfiguration.getProperty("topic"));

Comment: builder.stream(   "topicName", Consumed.with(jsonSerde, jsonSerde))

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743011/deserialise-a-pojo-in-kafka-streams