# Deserialise a POJO in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, pojo, apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka topic has messages of this format

```
user1,subject1,80|user1,subject2,90 

user2,subject1,70|user2,subject2,100 

and so on.
```

I have created User POJO as below.

```
class User implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -253687203767610477L;
private String userId;
private String subject;
private String marks;

public User(String userId, String subject, String marks) {
    super();
    this.userId = userId;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.marks = marks;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
public String getMarks() {
    return marks;
}
public void setMarks(String marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
}
}
```

Further I have created default key value serialization

```
streamProperties.put(
            StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
streamProperties.put(
            StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
```

I am trying to find count by userID as follows. Also I need User object to perform some other functionalities.

```
KTable<String, Long> wordCount = streamInput

    .flatMap(new KeyValueMapper<String, String, Iterable<KeyValue<String,User>>>() {

        @Override
        public Iterable<KeyValue<String, User>> apply(String key, String value) {
            String[] userObjects = value.split("|");
            List<KeyValue<String, User>> userList = new LinkedList<>();
            for(String userObject: userObjects) {
                String[] userData = userObject.split(",");
                userList.add(KeyValue.pair(userData[0],
                        new User(userData[0],userData[1],userData[2])));


            }
            return userList;
        }
    })

.groupByKey()
.count();
```

I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: com.example.testing.dao.User). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

I think I need to provide correct `Serde` for User Class.

Comment: You need to define your own deserializer class. Please show your attempts at this. Also find out the where the serializer is defined that the producer used

Comment: `class UserDeserializer implements Deserializer` would be a good start.

Comment: Are you sure your records are really two user objects in a string, though? Can you show the console consumer output with a max of 5 messages?

Comment: @cricket_007 No each message in kafka will have information of many user objects separated by Pipe delimiter. Each user information is separated by comma . Please check the constructor and each user message. That is why I have used flatMap

Comment: Can you give some example on UserDeserializer and how to provide serde for User while doing flatMap

Comment: I don't think your objects are pipe-delimted. The error is clearly saying that you cannot get a String from a `com.example.testing.dao.User` value type... I (nor anyone else) can write a deserializer without knowing how the object ***was serialized** to begin with*

Comment: I think the issue lies in the way you are producing messages and reading it from the Kafka Queue. Both needs to be serialized in same way. Try converting all messages at String Serializable and then run your code. It should work. If it works, try to change it to proper JSON serializer and then read it.

Comment: @CodeHunter you are exactly correct. I want to make String serialised Produced messages mapped to User POJO and work on it and finally stream the counts to a queue. It is simple in Storm with "implements Serializable" . I couldn't understand why I cannot modify it to a POJO.

Comment: @phaigeim If your issue is converting your POJO to KafkaMessage, then you need to use ObjectMapper. I believe you are having issues in parsing your POJO to json and then pass it to Kafka. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @CodeHunter I want to Create User Objects with my String messages in Kafka and use my User Objects for further transformations and actions such as aggregate and groupby. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with Value Serdes.

There are two version of function groupBy:

- `KStream::KGroupedStream<K, V> groupByKey();`
- `KStream::KGroupedStream<K, V> groupByKey(final Grouped<K, V> grouped);`

First version under the hood call second with `Grouped` with default Serdes (In your case it was for key and value `StringSerde`

Your `flatMap` map message to `KeyValue<String, User>` type so value was of type `User`.

Solution in your case would be instead using `groupByKey()` call `groupByKey(Grouped.with(keySerde, valSerde));`, with proper Serdes.

Comment: what would be a proper valSerde in this case?